# Combine ForEach Loops With ListItems

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a few ForEach loops that are looping to retrieve checked checkboxes in each  checkbox list. What I am trying to understand/figure out is how can I combine the ForEach loops into one. Below is what I currently have and currently works.

```
    For Each li As ListItem In allocationCheckList.Items
        customReportQueries(li.Value, li.Text, li)
    Next

    For Each li As ListItem In clientSpecificList.Items
        customReportQueries(li.Value, li.Text, li)
    Next

    For Each li As ListItem In dataStructureList.Items
        customReportQueries(li.Value, li.Text, li)
    Next
```

Comment: You can `Dim boxLists = {allocationCheckList, clientSpecificList, dataStructureList}` (or even use the `.Lists` property of them if it makes sense) and iterate over that array.

Comment: If what you have works, then why do you want to combine them? wouldn't that just make it less readable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consolidate like this:

calling block:

```
Private Sub SomeSub()

    customReportQueries(allocationCheckList.Items)
    customReportQueries(clientSpecificList.Items)
    customReportQueries(dataStructureList.Items)

End Sub
```

Changes customReportQueries Subroutine

```
Private Sub customReportQueries(checkBoxList As ListItemCollection)

    For Each li As ListItem In checkBoxList

        'Do what the old customReportQueries Subroutine did

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for you help. This was exactly what I was looking for.